# An analytic vector field on $S^3$ whose all orbits are dense (à la Seifert conjecture, 2)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems

Does there exist a real analytic vector field on $S^3$ all of whose orbits are dense? The second paragraph of page 285
Of this paper says that there is a vector field whose almost all orbits are dense:

http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/constructionchamps.pdf

Is there an example of such a vector field which belongs to the Lie algebra of all left-invariant vector fields of the Lie group $S^3$?

Comment: Every orbit of a left invariant vector field is closed (it is contained in the translate of a torus).

Comment: $SO(4)=SO(3) ⊕ SO(3)$, and pick two incommensurable circle actions.

Comment: @abx  Kronecker foliation is invariant in 2 torus. So in S^3 case os not possible that an orbit would be non closed?

Comment: Real-analytic counterexamples to Seifert conjecture were published by Kuperberg and Kuperberg in Annals of Math., 1996.

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: the difference is that $S^3=SU(2)$ is semi-simple. Every element is contained in a circle.

Comment: @Misha Yes but that counter example does not satisfy the condition of this question: the condition is: all orbits would be dense.

Comment: The vector field mentioned in Ghys' paper is on $S^2$, not on $S^3$.

Comment: @abx   By Poincare -Bendixon theorem(or some similar methods) one can easilly shows that $S^2$ does not admit any vector field with a dense orbit.

Comment: @abx  in that paragraph of the paper of Ghys, however he starts the paragraph  with 2 dimensional sphere but during the remaining part of the paragraph he  is considering 3- sphere.Right?

Comment: OK, you are right. The vector field is actually on $SO(3)$ (= the unitary tangent bundle to $S^2$), hence it lifts to $S^3$.

Comment: @abx yes exactly. He consider the "revetment" de unit tangent bundle of $S^2$.